# Django - InternalError caused by RAISE EXCEPTION in a postgres trigger

Tags: django, postgresql, exception, triggers, controls

I'm new with Django and I need some help,
I want to restrict the **editing** of a model instance, if there's a value in the X field and you try to change any field you get a message.

Since I'm using postgres, I thought about using a trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION checkear_lb()
RETURNS TRIGGER  
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $$
BEGIN
--Check
     IF not (old.linea_base_id is null) THEN
          RAISE EXCEPTION 'You cant edit this because';
     END IF;
RETURN NULL; --I also tried with NEW
END;
$$

create trigger tarea_con_lb
before update
on "Desarrollo_tarea"
for each row execute procedure checkear_lb();
```

It works, but I get this

```
InternalError at /admin/Desarrollo/tarea/1/change/
You can't edit this because
CONTEXT:  función PL/pgSQL checkear_lb() en la línea 5 en RAISE

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/Desarrollo/tarea/1/change/
Django Version:     3.0.3
Exception Type:     InternalError
Exception Value:    

You cant edit this because
CONTEXT:  función PL/pgSQL checkear_lb() en la línea 5 en RAISE

Exception Location:     C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in _execute,     line 86
Python Executable:  C:\Python38\python.exe
Python Version:     3.8.2
Python Path:
```

Also tried overriding the save function, same result

```
class Tarea(models.Model):
....
#linea base
linea_base = models.ForeignKey('LineaBase', null=True, blank=True, help_text='Linea Base', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)  # , on_delete=models.CASCADE

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.linea_base:
        if (self.og_version != self.version):
            raise Exception('You cant edit this because')
        else:
            super(Tarea, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        super(Tarea, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is obviously caused by the trigger, and I was wondering if there's a better way to handle it inside django, or just a way to handle this.
Thanks.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. If you just want to prevent the editing without notifying the user, then remove the `RAISE EXCEPTION` . If you want the `EXCEPTION` message to propagate to user, keep the `RAISE EXCEPTION` and then wrap your transaction with a `try/except` that catches the `InternalError` exception and passes the message to the user.

Comment: You may have a slight misconception here. The "InternalError ..." is a  Django exception NOT a Postgres exception. While it is true the error stems from the trigger, Django is raising it in response to the trigger properly executing as it is written. Postgres itself will raise the exception as indicated, but there is no further error. See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bd4a954232e87e22352373bdc3e2de63).